# Could someone help me translate this short code snippet into python?

Tags: python, actionscript, matrix, numpy

I'm trying to wrap my head around coordinate systems for isometric tiles using [this tutorial](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/03/27/isometric-coordinate-systems-the-modern-way/).  I've got it mostly figured out except for the last snippet, which I am copying below to avoid unnecessary clicking =)

```
/**
* Intersect two line segments defined by A->B and C->D
*
* Returns the time of intersection along A->B
*/
public function RayIntersect(A : Vector2, B : Vector2, C : Vector2, D : Vector2) : Number
{
    // turn C->D into a plane...
    const n : Vector2 = D.Sub(C).m_Perp;

    // ...and do the regular plane vs ray maths
    const numerator : Number = C.Sub(A).Dot(n);
    const denom : Number = B.Sub(A).Dot(n);

    return numerator / denom;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what language this is written in (Java? ActionScript?), but the idea is to to take screen coordinates and to project them onto map space.  The figure below gives a schematic overview of what's being done:

[image]

Given a point `P`, we want to find the point of intersection along the `up` axis and the `right` axis.  Unfortunately my matrix algebra is (very) rusty so I'm having trouble deducing what's being done in the code.  A python translation would go a long way towards helping me figure this out.

One important point:  I'm using a 2D numpy array to represent my map, so matrix transformations should ideally be handled through numpy.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: see https://github.com/natural/java2python for a tool to do it

Comment: It's definitely not Java. It might be ActionScript (Flash).

Comment: @RachelGallen, Thanks for the edit and thanks for the suggestion!  Will java2python choke on language-specific libraries?

Comment: @TedHopp, Out of curiosity, what makes you so sure it's not Java?

Comment: The parameter list `A : Vector` - that cannot be plain Java. (Same for variable declarations)

Comment: Two things indicate that this is not Java: Java doesn't have the `const` keyword; and parameter and local variable types in Java appear before the identifiers (`Vector2 a`, etc.).

Comment: @Mat, I suspect there may be library imports that the author isn't showing us =/

Comment: @blz: that can't be done with a fancy import, those can't change the language syntax. The author of that page doesn't claim it's Java either, and the demo at the end is Flash. It's Action Script.

Comment: @Mat, good point and nice catch!  That's one question resolved =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def ray_intersect(A, B, C, D):
   """ 
   Intersect two line segments defined by A->B and C->D
   Returns the time of intersection along A->B
   """

   # turn C->D into a plane...
   E = D-C
   n = np.array((-E[1], E[0]))
   # ...and do the regular plane vs ray maths
   numerator = np.dot(C-A, n)
   denom = np.dot(B-A, n)

   return numerator / denom;
```